# Bootstrap compiling both default and customized styles

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm trying to modify my website based on a CMS which relies mostly on Bootstrap. I saw that after compiling sass files, in the compiled CSS I have both the default css selectors and the overridden ones. For example:

```
template.css?d544b92…:12881
a {
    color: #1d60a1;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

template.css?d544b92…:264
a {
    color: #1d60a1;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

The overridden ones are used, as expected but, though, having both in the compiled file makes it much larger. If someone could give me a little help I would really appreciate it. This is the normal behavior of bootstrap( v4) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you theming bootstrap or overriding it? If overriding, bootstrap would still be compiled in its natural state and your custom styles afterwards.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is integrated in the CMS and I have in my themplate's SCSS folder a custom variables file and some duplicated ones from Bootstrap. On wich I made the edits.

Comment: It seems as though they are compiling separately and simply overriding bootstraps styles with yours. You would need a deeper integration to import bootstrap theming. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/